# How to inject or find validaters by entity type in fluent validation?

Tags: c#, fluent

how inject or find validators by entity type in fluent validation?
i have following classes and want validate entities by fluent validation

```
    public class BaseEntity {}

    public class Article :BaseEntity
    {
         public string Name {get;set;}
    }

    public class ArticleValidator : AbstractValidator<Article>
    {
         public ArticleValidator()
         {
              RuleFor(x => x.Name ).NotEmpty().Length(0,512);
         }
    }
```

and have extentions for BaseEntity:

```
    public static ValidationResult Validate(this BaseEntity entity)
    {
        //????and here how i can find entity validator by type of entity  and  validate it and return result.
    }

    public class ArticleService
    {
         public void AddArticle(Article aricle)
         {
             var result = article.Validate();
             if(result.IsValid)
                 ;.......
         }
    }
```

Comment: @VaibhavMule The code pictured in the question is C#, not Java.

Comment: Would be better to let DI handle this for you, assuming you're on .NET Core/5+. An extension method corners you in to reflection. You could have a validation service that takes the `IServiceProvider` and if your validators are registered, you can just do `serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IValidator<Article>>()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using FluentValidation;
using FluentValidation.Results;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var c = new MyClass();
            var result = Validate(c);
        }

        public static ValidationResult Validate(object c)
        {
            if (c == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("c");

            var vt = typeof (AbstractValidator<>);
            var et = c.GetType();
            var evt = vt.MakeGenericType(et);

            var validatorType = FindValidatorType(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), evt);

            var validatorInstance = (IValidator)Activator.CreateInstance(validatorType);
            return validatorInstance.Validate(c);
        }


        public static Type FindValidatorType(Assembly assembly, Type evt)
        {
            if (assembly == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("assembly");
            if (evt == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("evt");
            return assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsSubclassOf(evt));
        }
    }


    public class MyClassValidator : AbstractValidator<MyClass>
    {

    }

    public class MyClass
    {

    }
}
```

Make sure your concrete validators have at least one parameterless constructor.
Good luck

Answer (score 4):

Inject `IServiceProvider _servicesCollection` into the controller (or wherever you're trying to validate the model from)

Define the following method

```
public Task<ValidationResult> ValidateModelAsync(object model)
{
    var validatorType = typeof(IValidator<>).MakeGenericType(model.GetType());
    var validator = (IValidator)_servicesCollection.GetRequiredService(validatorType);

    var validationContextType = typeof(ValidationContext<>).MakeGenericType(model.GetType());
    var validationContext = (IValidationContext)Activator.CreateInstance(validationContextType, model);

    return validator.ValidateAsync(validationContext);
}
```

Use

```
[HttpPost("api/todo")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Todo(RequestModel model)
{
    var validaitonResult = await ValidateModelAsync(model);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ValidationAspect : MethodInterception
{
    private Type _validatorType;
    public ValidationAspect(Type validatorType)
    {
        if (!typeof(IValidator).IsAssignableFrom(validatorType))
        {
            throw new System.Exception("This is not a validation class.");
        }

        _validatorType = validatorType;
    }
    protected override void OnBefore(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var validator = (IValidator)Activator.CreateInstance(_validatorType);
        var entityType = _validatorType.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var entities = invocation.Arguments.Where(t => t.GetType() == entityType);
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            ValidationTool.Validate(validator, entity);
        }
    }
}

public class BrandInsertDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<BrandInsertDto>
{
    public BrandInsertDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(p => p.Name).NotNull();
        RuleFor(p => p.Name).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(p => p.Name).MaximumLength(50);
        RuleFor(p => p.Name.Length).GreaterThanOrEqualTo(2);
    }
}


public class BrandInsertDto : IDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.